# how to Find the tree depth in neo4j from root to the maximum leaf

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to find the depth of the tree

I have found this solution but I do not know whether it's true for all the cases:

```
MATCH p=(parent)-[:RELATES*]->(child)
WHERE id(parent) = 30
RETURN p
ORDER BY length(p) DESC
limit 1
```

This gives me the longest path, but 
firstly: I don't know if it's always valid.
Secondly: I want the output to be a number of the depth not the List itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @cybersam mentioned with little bit of tweaking:

```
MATCH p=(parent)-[:RELATES*]->(child)
WHERE ID(parent) = 30 AND NOT (child)-[:RELATES]>()
RETURN LENGTH(p) + 1 AS maxLth
ORDER BY maxLth DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Technically, this is actually calculating the "depth" plus 1.

Answer (score 0):

This query should work:

```
MATCH p=(parent)-[:RELATES*]->(child)
WHERE ID(parent) = 30 AND NOT (child)-[:RELATES]>()
RETURN LENGTH(p) AS maxLth
ORDER BY maxLth DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Although not strictly necessary, it only considers paths where `child` is a leaf.

Comment: In standard tree theory terminology, the "depth" of a tree is determined by the number of edges, not vertices.